# how to transfer one page to other by using pagecontroller in ios

Tags: ios, objective-c-blocks

This question has been asked before but i have difficulty among those.
as i have created pagecontroller and in every page there is one image. but i want other page not image. i have tried this for image but confusion for page.

```
    - (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    UIBarButtonItem *button=[[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithTitle:@"Go" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(Go)];
    UIBarButtonItem *button1=[[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithTitle:@"Go" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(Go)];
    [self.navigationItem setRightBarButtonItem:button];
    [self.navigationItem setLeftBarButtonItem:button1];
    self.navigationItem.title=@"Navigation";
   //Scroll View

    imgarray =[[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"images.jpg",@"images.jpg",@"images.jpg",@"images.jpg",@"images.jpg", nil];
    for(int i=0;i<[imgarray count];i++)
    {
        CGRect frame;
        frame.origin.x=[UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width*i;
        frame.origin.y=0;
        frame.size=[UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size;
        UIImageView *imageview=[[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:frame];
        imageview.image=[UIImage imageNamed:[imgarray objectAtIndex:i]];
        [self.Scrollview addSubview:imageview];
    }

       // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.
    Scrollview.contentSize=CGSizeMake([UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width*[imgarray count],Scrollview.frame.size.height );
}


-(void)Go
{
    BAR2 *bar=[[BAR2 alloc]initWithNibName:@"BAR2" bundle:nil];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:bar animated:YES];
}


#pragma mark-UIScrollView Delegate
-(void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
    CGFloat pageWidth=self.Scrollview.frame.size.width;
    int page=floor((self.Scrollview.contentOffset.x-pageWidth/2)/pageWidth)+1;
    self.pagecontrol.currentPage=page;
}
```

now i having confusion that i have created array for each image now my question is what to create for new page or there may be different way.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I think your problem is that you can not push view from the current view right?

Comment: no i can push by using navigation controller. but i want to transfer a page having some data using pagecontroller. in my code i pushed image

Comment: where to transfer a page ?

Comment: as i want to move one page to another. in my above  codethere is 5 images and they moved one by one

Comment: Ok so you need views instead of images in the scrollview?

Comment: yes now you got my point.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/103268/discussion-between-narendra-pandey-and-jaimish).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
You can take Three or viewcontrollers and Give them approipiate Storyboard id !!!! have Look At My code !! 

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
   ViewController1 *Chart1 = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"FirstViewController"];
    ViewController2 *Chart2 ;
    ViewController3 *Chart3;

    NSArray *controllersArray =[NSArray arrayWithObjects:Chart1, Chart2, Chart3,nil];


     self.pageViewController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"PageViewController"];
    self.pageViewController.dataSource=self;
    self.pageViewController.delegate=self;

   [self.pageViewController setViewControllers:controllersArray direction:UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirectionForward animated:NO completion:nil];


  self.pageViewController.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 72, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height - 30);

    [self addChildViewController:self.pageViewController];
    [self.view addSubview:self.pageViewController.view];
    [self.pageViewController didMoveToParentViewController:self];
}


- (UIViewController *)pageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController
      viewControllerBeforeViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController
{


    if ([viewController isKindOfClass:[ViewController3 class]]) {


        ViewController2 *pvc = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"sec"];
                return pvc;
}
    else if([viewController isKindOfClass:[ViewController2 class]]) {


        ViewController1 *pvc = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"FirstViewController"];
             return pvc;

    }
   else
   {
       return nil;
   }
}
- (UIViewController *)pageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController
       viewControllerAfterViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController
{
    if ([viewController isKindOfClass:[ViewController1 class]])
    {

        ViewController2 *tvc = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"sec"];


         return tvc;
    }

    else if ([viewController isKindOfClass:[ViewController2 class]])
    {

        ViewController3 *tvc = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"third"];


        return tvc;
    }
else
{
    return nil ;


}

}
```